Projection with transformation returns unexpected results using GeoPandas compared to ArcPy
I am using GeoPandas to project a geodataframe of polylines representing water crossing locations across the USA from ESRI:102039 (NAD 1983 USGS Contiguous USA Albers) to ESPG:3857 (WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator -- Spherical Mercator). I am attempting to replicate a similar workflow I am currently running in ArcPy. The goal is for the two workflows to create identical outputs to allow for flexibility in using ArcPy vs GeoPandas moving forward.
In GeoPandas:    line_gdf_proj = line_gdf.to_crs("EPSG:3857")
In ArcPy:  arcpy.Project_management(in_lines, lines_project, arcpy.SpatialReference(3857))

However, when I run the projection using gpd.to_crs(), the resulting polylines are shifted ~ 3ft  from the resulting polylines produced from the arcpy.Project_mananagement() tool. The discrepancy is consistent in all features across the US. In the screenshot below the input lines are in blue, GeoPandas projected lines are in red, showing the shift. The ArcPy projected lines are in green on the right panel, as expected they are directly coincident with the input lines in the map viewer.
Should I not be expecting the projection in GeoPandas to align perfectly with the projection in ArcPy, or is something unexpected happening? My best guess is that pyproj working under the hood in GeoPandas is not apply the same WGS_1984_(ITRF00)_To_NAD_1983 transformation; however maybe my assumptions that these two projection would produce identical (if not very similar results) is incorrect.
I did test performing the projections directly with pyproj using Transformer.from_crs("ESRI:102039", "EPSG:3857") and got the same results as with GeoPandas.
Versioning: GeoPandas 0.14.1; Shapely 2.0.4; pyproj 3.6.1


This seems a likely datum transformation difference. Whether you should expect it to not be equal is fairly subjective.

GeoPandas, Shapely, pyproj, and the rest of the GIS world (besides ArcGIS Pro) do not yet contain native methods to implement this ~1m shift, which is apparently related to actual movement of the North American plate. The "null transformation" is the widespread default, even still within ArcGIS Pro's own python lib, in arcpy.Geometry.projectAS().
The "ITRF00 shift", as I've been referring to it, can be disabled as others mention, but assuming you're already committed to a database that uses it and would like to be able to convert using open-source tools, here are a set of functions to do so in pyproj / geopandas (see main section at bottom for usage example).
Disclaimer, I'm a Developer, not an expert on coordinate system math.
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import Transformer
from shapely.ops import transform
from typing import Union, Tuple


# seven params pulled from ESRI ITRF00 (EPSG:108190) definition:
# https://github.com/Esri/projection-engine-db-doc/blob/440e9f0e7184ce00b567cf6531d54d8c15d24ed8/proj4/esri#L2033
ITRF00_PARAMS = [
    0.9956000824677655,
    -1.901299877314078,
    -0.5215002840524426,
    -0.02591500053005733,
    -0.009425998542707753,
    -0.01159900118427752,
    0.00062000005129903
]


def proj4_itrf00(
    crs_from: Union[int, str],
    crs_to: Union[int, str],
) -> str:
    """
    Generates a proj4 string for the given coordinate system conversion, corrected to account for ITRF00 ~1.3m shift
    
    Args:
        crs_from (Union[int, str]): EPSG code or string representation of coord sys to convert from
        crs_to (Union([int, str]): EPSG code or string representation of coord sys to convert to

    Returns:
        str: proj4 of given coord transformation with ITRF00 adjustment
    """

    # generate original proj4 with null wgs84 transform
    t = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from, crs_to, always_xy=True)
    proj4 = t.to_proj4()

    # convert to string
    itrf00_str = ",".join([str(p) for p in ITRF00_PARAMS])
    
    # replace null transform with ITRF00 transform
    return proj4.replace("+ellps=WGS84", f"+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84={itrf00_str} +no_defs")


def gdf_to_crs_itrf00(
    gdf: gpd.GeoDataFrame,
    crs_to: Union[int, str],
) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """
    Converts a geodataframe to a new coordinate system, applying the ITRF00 adjustment.

    Args:
        gdf (gpd.Geodataframe): input geodataframe
        crs_to (Union[int, str]): EPSG code or string representation of coordinate system to convert to

    Returns:
        gpd.GeoDataFrame: input geodataframe, but converted to new coordinate system with ITRF00 adjustment
    """

    # define crs_from using the gdf
    crs_from = gdf.crs

    # get proj4 associated with this transform
    proj4 = proj4_itrf00(crs_from, crs_to)

    # define pyproj transformer
    t = Transformer.from_pipeline(proj4)

    # apply transformation
    gdf["geometry"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda geom: transform(t.transform, geom))

    # update crs property
    gdf.crs = crs_to

    return gdf


def xy_transform_itrf00(
    x: float,
    y: float,
    crs_from: Union[int, str],
    crs_to: Union[int, str],
) -> Tuple[float, float]:
    """
    Convert coordinates, applying the ITRF00 adjustment

    Args:
        x (float): input longitude
        y (float): input latitude
        from_crs (Union[int, str]): EPSG code or string representation of coordinate system to convert from
        to_crs (Union[int, str]): EPSG code or string representation of coordinate system to convert to

    Returns:
        Tuple(float, float): output longitude, output latitude
    """
    
    # get proj4 associated with this transform
    proj4 = proj4_itrf00(crs_from, crs_to)

    # define pyproj transformer
    t = Transformer.from_pipeline(proj4)

    # apply transformation to coordinates
    return t.transform(x, y)


# usage example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    x = 1890644.67328 # example longitude in EPSG:3734
    y = 570966.50785 # example latitude in EPSG:3734

    spc = 3734 # ohio north ft us state plane epsg
    wm = 3857 # web mercator epsg

    print('\norig state plane coords:')
    print(x)
    print(y)

    print('\nweb mercator via pyproj (null transform):')
    pyproj_standard = Transformer.from_crs(f"EPSG:{spc}", f"EPSG:{wm}", always_xy=True)
    x_, y_ = pyproj_standard.transform(x, y)
    print(x_)
    print(y_)

    print('\nweb mercator via custom (ITRF00 transform):')
    x_, y_ = xy_transform_itrf00(x, y, crs_from=spc, crs_to=wm)
    print(x_)
    print(y_)

    print('\nrevert to orig state plane coords:')
    x__, y__ = xy_transform_itrf00(x_, y_, crs_from=wm, crs_to=spc)
    print(x__)
    print(y__)

    print()


thanks for the well documented response

As Vince mentioned, this is a classic shift between NAD83 and WGS84. One or the other is doing either no geographic/datum transformation or a 'null' transformation (actually a null method, or parameters are zeroes.
Try using the Project tool and set the transformation to NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984. That's null transformation. If the results line up with GeoPandas, you'll know that GeoPandas isn't performing a transformation between NAD83 and WGS84.

I tried setting the "null" transformation and that does indeed reproduce the output of GeoPandas, so I think it is safe to say the transformation in GeoPandas is not happening. Now as to why, that is still a mystery and definitely makes me wary of trusting projections with transformations in GeoPandas moving forward.
